# Does the physical copy of Batman #5 have rotated pages?

Tags: comics, dc, batman, comixology

I have been reading Batman #5 (from the New 52) in Comixology, and when Batman is in the labyrinth some pages are rotated to be at 90 degrees or 180 degrees from the normal vertical axis.  Is this an artifact from the physical copy, potentialy indicating Batman's altered mental state, or is it just a bug in the Comixology version?

I am asking because if it is in the physical version, I think it is a clever construction... But it drove me absolutely nuts reading it on an iPad with its autorotations!

Comment: Fun fact: I filed a bug report on that and got confirmation of the intent by Comixology. But I agree, autorotate makes this rather unpleasant...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. In the printed version on pages 14 -19 (counting the ad pages) the images are in landscape on the pages instead of portrait. The pages 20 and 25 are upside down in portrait mode.